# Login always fails Paypal MPL on Android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, android-library

I'm building an Android app where the user pays for a booking via PayPal. It's just a one off simple payment from the user to the business, nothing more.

I've got the SDK's from here https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index

I chose the Mobile Payment Libraries rather than the Mobile Express Checkout Library, do you reckon I chose right ? MPL allowed me to dynamically create a paypal pay button and the layout works perfectly.

I have followed the guide that comes with the SDK, it's title is "Mobile Payments Library Developer Guide and Reference – Android OS Edition"

The **main problem** is when I test the button, I click on it to make a test payment in sandbox, it asks me to login, I try to login via my personal account it always fails, I also tried a friend's account to login, still always fails.

Here is part of the code I used:

```
paypalObject = PayPal.initWithAppID(getApplicationContext(), "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX); // SANDBOX

CheckoutButton launchPayPalButton = paypalObject.getCheckoutButton(M_PaymentOptions.this, PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
params.bottomMargin = 10;
launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params);
launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
        newPayment.setSubtotal(BigDecimal.valueOf(10.f));
        newPayment.setCurrencyType("GBP");
        newPayment.setRecipient("private@private.co.uk"); // changed the email deliberately for privacy reasons
        newPayment.setMerchantName("My Company");
        Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, M_PaymentOptions.this);
        M_PaymentOptions.this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
    }
});

((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.m_RelativeLayout)).addView(launchPayPalButton);
```

Comment: Any log available? I'd suspect your testing environment is not allowed to use real accounts and you'd need to create test/development accounts to test it.

Comment: yeah that's very true, how do I create a test account ?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to login using real paypal accounts in the sandbox which is wrong, had to create a test account from here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts

Thanks for Marek for his comment

> Any log available? I'd suspect your testing environment is not allowed
>   to use real accounts and you'd need to create test/development
>   accounts to test it. – Marek Sebera